# Could not find or load main class in Spring Application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I create my web site on Spring and everything was going well, but in one second my application stopped starting and I see such a mistake:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class com.MusicJournal.MusicJournal.MusicJournalApplication
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.MusicJournal.MusicJournal.MusicJournalApplication
```

This is my main class:

```
package com.MusicJournal.MusicJournal;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class MusicJournalApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MusicJournalApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

I tryed to rebuild project, reload IDE and PC, but it didn't help. It looks like a bug. So, how can I fix it?

P.S. I use Intellije IDEA; Structure of my project on screenshot
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W7MyN.png)

Comment: Please take care of java naming conventions. package names should be lower case

Comment: I didn't change anything in the package names and the application always worked correctly

Comment: Try to rebuild you project

Comment: I've already tried it - it doesn't help!

Comment: Can you share a picture of the file structure and how you run the program?

Comment: I run project using green triangle near class name

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-run-your-first-spring-boot-application-in-intellij-idea/

Comment: Thank you, but I know wery well how run projects in intelleje idea. Also, I taked screenshot which reflects structure of my project, pleese, look at it

Answer (score 0):

Obviously something is wrong with your project. I can see the outer project `MusicJournal` and then the other `MusicJournal` project inside. This is kind of a weird identification of the project by Intellij IDEA.

You should delete your project from Intellij IDEA, take a look at the directory hierarchy, and then import the project again.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, what I see in your picture is you have two MusicJournal projects with two .idea folders which include the metainformation of you projects. They may cause conflict. Try to recreate structure with only one project so that you have only one .idea, .mvn etc. folders and build project again

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the main class in the pom.xml file

```xml
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.18.RELEASE</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>your main class</mainClass>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>repackage</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```